# How to show Sprite in UI for My 2D Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a rig to my character(**Sprite**) and I use it as I want, but I need to display it as a UI Image in Canvas, how can I solve this?

sprite extension of my character is .psb

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Both Image and Sprite are 2D meshes on the screen.

Comment: I'm making a question game on Canvas and I have a character with a rig.

Comment: I mean you already have a sprite on the screen, why do you need draw it in a Image too?

Comment: I use orthographic camera because I do a few things like puzzle and I show it on canvas.